# ngx-dropzone-wrapper + .NET Core Web API

Tags: .net, angular, asp.net-core-webapi, dropzone

For some reason my collection of IFormFiles is always empty when sending files from my Angular 5 application to my .NET Core Web API. I'm guessing I'm just over looking a configuration somewhere. Does anyone see anything wrong with this? Note that I'm using ngx-dropzone-wrapper (https://github.com/zefoy/ngx-dropzone-wrapper). Thanks in advance!

**home.component.html**

```
<!-- Container -->
<div class="container">
    <form>
        <dropzone class="dropzone-container" [message]="'Click or drag groups of files to upload them to the Data Entry API'" (error)="uploadError($event)"
            (success)="uploadSuccess($event)" (queueComplete)="complete($event)" (sending)="sending($event)">
        </dropzone>
        <button (click)="processQueue()">Go</button>
    </form>
</div>
<!-- End Container -->
```

**home.component.ts**

```
import { Component, ViewEncapsulation, ElementRef, ViewChild, AfterViewInit } from '@angular/core';
import { DropzoneComponent, DropzoneDirective, DropzoneConfigInterface } from 'ngx-dropzone-wrapper';
import { DataEntryService } from '../../services/data-entry.service';
import Swal from 'sweetalert2'

@Component({
  selector: 'app-home',
  templateUrl: './home.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./home.component.scss'],
  encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None
})
export class HomeComponent implements AfterViewInit {

  // References to the dropzone component
  @ViewChild(DropzoneComponent) componentRef: DropzoneComponent;
  dropzone: any;

  // Flag to determine whether or not the 'Yes' button should be shown
  uploading: boolean = false;

  //** Constructor */
  constructor(private _dataEntryService: DataEntryService) { }

  /** Lifecycle hook that is called after a this component's view has been fully initialized */
  ngAfterViewInit() {

    // Get a reference ot the dropzone component
    this.dropzone = this.componentRef.directiveRef.dropzone();
  }

  /** 
   * Sends all queued files to our API (not the Data Entry API)
   * Triggered when the user clicks the 'Yes' button
   * @returns {void}
   * */
  processQueue(): void {

    console.log('Processing the queue');

    this.dropzone.processQueue();
  }

  /** 
   * Gets the xhr object and the formData objects as second and third parameters, so they can be modified or additional data can be added
   * Triggered by dropzone just before each file is sent
   * @param {any} args - The dropzone arguments
   * @returns {void}
   * */
  sending(args: any): void {

    console.log('Sending files');
    console.log(args);
  }

  /** 
   * Displays an error messages if one or more files were rejected by dropzone
   * Triggered by dropzone when an upload was either successfull or erroneous
   * @param {any} args - The dropzone arguments
   * @returns {void}
   * */
  complete(args: any): void {

    console.log('File upload comlpete');

    let accepted = this.dropzone.getAcceptedFiles();
    let rejected = this.dropzone.getRejectedFiles();
    let queued = this.dropzone.getQueuedFiles();
    let uploading = this.dropzone.getUploadingFiles();

    console.log('Accepted:  ' + accepted.length);
    console.log('Rejected:  ' + rejected.length);
    console.log('Queued:  ' + queued.length);
    console.log('Uploading:  ' + uploading.length);

    if (queued.length === 0 && uploading.length === 0) {

      if (rejected.length > 0) {

        Swal({
          type: 'error',
          title: 'Rejected Files',
          text: rejected.length + ' of the files that you uploaded were rejected. Please close this modal, correct your errors and try again.'
        });

        this.uploading = true;
      }
    }
  }

  /** 
   * For now, this just writes success messages to the console for debugging purposes
   * Triggered when a file has been uploaded successfully
   * @param {any} args - The dropzone arguments
   * @returns {void}
   * */
  uploadSuccess(args: any): void {

    console.log('Upload successful');

    if (args && args[0]) {
      console.log('File Uploaded:  ' + args[0].name);
    }
  }

  /** 
 * For now, this just writes error messages to the console for debugging purposes
 * Triggered when an upload error occurs
 * @param {any} args - The dropzone arguments
 * @returns {void}
 * */
  uploadError(args: any): void {

    console.error('Upload Error');

    if (args && args[1]) {
      console.error(args[1]);
    }
  }

}
```

**config**

```
const DEFAULT_DROPZONE_CONFIG: DropzoneConfigInterface = {

  // Where we should send the files (Default: null)
  url: 'http://localhost:61143/api/xray',

  // Whether the queue will be processed automatically
  autoProcessQueue: false,

  // Optional oject to send additional headers to the server (Default: null)
  headers: null,

  // How many file uploads to process in parallel (Default: null)
  parallelUploads: 500,

  // Name of the file parameter that gets transferred (Default: 'file')
  paramName: 'file',

  // Maximum file size for the upload files in megabytes (Default: null)
  maxFilesize: 500,

  // Comma separated list of mime types or file extensions (Default: null)
  acceptedFiles: '.jpg, .dcm, .dicom',

  // Whether to send multiple files in one request (Default: null)
  uploadMultiple: true,

  // Whether thumbnails for images should be generated
  createImageThumbnails: false,

  // Whether to add a link to every file preview to remove or cancel (if already uploading) the file
  addRemoveLinks: true
};
```

**.NET Core Web API Controller**

```
using System.Linq;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using DataEntry.Data;
using System;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace DataEntry.API.Controllers
{
    [Produces("application/json")]
    [Route("api/xray")]
    public class XRayController : Controller
    {
        private readonly DataEntryContext _db;

        public XRayController(DataEntryContext db)
        {
            _db = db;
        }

        // POST: api/xray
        [HttpPost]
        public IActionResult AddXRay(ICollection<IFormFile> files)
        {
            try
            {
                if (files == null || files.Count == 0)
                {
                    // Always 0 files here
                    throw new Exception("One or more JPG or DICOM file is required to upload X-rays.");
                }

                return Ok();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                return BadRequest(ex.Message);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I know this is a bit older, but were you able to figure this out? Running into something similar.

Comment: In my case it ended up being my dropzone was sending up a Content-Type header (my own accidental doing) that was causing my request's form.files to be weird, and thereby not read as files.

Comment: I am trying to call the API from a service passing the object for request body. I am getting the object passed as request body in the API but not able to get the File Info. I want to send a person's details like Name etc along with the Profile picture uploaded. So sending the picture alone is not going to work for me as it would incur two requests to be sent.
Could you help me with that?

Answer (score 0):

You can try replace ICollection to IFormFile[]

Comment: Hello... I change ICollection<IFormFile> to IFormFile[]. Another option is You can try using Request.Forms.

Answer (score 0):

You should put the paramName in a function (ie. paramName: () => 'files'). The reason can be found in the dropzone.js file itself:

```
// @options.paramName can be a function taking one parameter rather than a string.
// A parameter name for a file is obtained simply by calling this with an index number.
  _getParamName(n) {
    if (typeof this.options.paramName === "function") {
      return this.options.paramName(n);
    } else {
      return `${this.options.paramName}${this.options.uploadMultiple ? `[${n}]` : ""}`;
    }
  }
```

What you want to achieve is to prevent the assignment of an index numnber (eg. file[0]) to the paramName or else the paramName isn't the same as in the .NET Core Web API Controller.

This is something not documented, I had to find it myself too by diving into the source code.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is in your config. change

```
paramName: file // to 
paramName: files
```